# Bash - output of command seems to be an integer but "[" complains

Tags: bash, scripting

I am checking to see if a process on a remote server has been killed.  The code I'm using is:

```
if [ `ssh -t -t -i id_dsa headless@remoteserver.com "ps -auxwww |grep pipeline| wc -l" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//'` -lt 3 ]
then 
  echo "PIPELINE STOPPED SUCCESSFULLY"
  exit 0
else
  echo "PIPELINE WAS NOT STOPPED SUCCESSFULLY"
  exit 1
fi
```

However when I execute this I get:

```
    : integer expression expected
PIPELINE WAS NOT STOPPED SUCCESSFULLY
1
```

The actual value returned is "1" with no whitespace.  I checked that by:

```
vim <(ssh -t -t -i id_dsa headless@remoteserver.com "ps -auxwww |grep pipeline| wc -l" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
```

and then ":set list" which showed only the integer and a line feed as the returned value.

I'm at a loss here as to why this is not working.

Comment: Instead of `grep pipeline| wc -l` try using `grep -c pipeline`

Comment: When I run the command, I'm seeing a `\r\n` at the end of the number which is probably throwing off the comparison. To "fix" it quick, I through in another `sed` piped after the first one: `...| sed -e 's/\r*$//'`. It then worked without the error. I'm not sure what's tossing in the `\r`. So your whole `ssh` line would look like: `ssh -t -t -i id_dsa headless@remoteserver.com "ps -auxwww |grep pipeline| wc -l" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed -e 's/\r*$//'`

Comment: It was adding that extra \r, so you're sed command worked.  Thanks, I'd vote your answer up but you didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: Why are you forcing tty allocation in your ssh command?  That should only be necessary for screen-based commands, which "ps" is not.  Drop that and your whole command becomes simpler since you won't need the sed.

Answer (score 1):

If the output of the `ssh` command is truly just an integer preceded by optional tabs, then you shouldn't need the `sed` command; the shell will strip the leading and/or trailing whitespace as unnecessary before using it as an operand for the `-lt` operator.

```
if [ $(ssh -tti id_dsa headless@remoteserver.com "ps -auxwww | grep -c pipeline") -lt 3 ]; then
```

It is possible that result of the `ssh` is not the same when you run it manually as when it runs in the shell. You might try saving it in a variable so you can output it before testing it in your script:

```
result=$( ssh -tti id_dsa headless@remoteserver.com "ps -auxwww | grep -c pipeline" )
if [ $result -lt 3 ];
```

Comment: Didn't know that the shell would strip the extra whitespace, thanks.  I've tried saving it into a variable (exactly as you wrote above) and the results are the same.

Comment: What is the value of `result`? If it is the empty string, as your original error message implies, then the problem is with the set of processes that you expect to be returned by the remote call to `ps`.

Comment: I suspect it's the tty allocation that's causing the problem.  For me, that makes ssh report when the connection is closed rather than just returning the output.

Answer (score 0):

The return value you get is not entirely a digit. Maybe some shell-metacharacter/linefeed/whatever gets into your way here:

```
#!/bin/bash

var=$(ssh -t -t -i id_dsa headless@remoteserver.com "ps auxwww |grep -c pipeline")

echo $var

# just to prove my point here 
# Remove all digits, and look wether there is a rest -> then its not integer
test -z "$var" -o -n "`echo $var | tr -d '[0-9]'`" && echo not-integer

# get out all the digits to use them for the arithmetic comparison
var2=$(grep -o "[0-9]" <<<"$var")

echo $var2


if [[ $var2 -lt 3 ]]
then
    echo "PIPELINE STOPPED SUCCESSFULLY"
    exit 0
else
    echo "PIPELINE WAS NOT STOPPED SUCCESSFULLY"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As user mbratch noticed I was getting a "\r" in the returned value in addition to the expected "\n".  So I changed my sed script so that it stripped out the "\r" instead of the whitespace (which chepner pointed out was unnecessary).

```
sed -e 's/\r*$//'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Accepted Answer per Comments

As @lurker pointed out there an extra '\r\n' showing up in @phileas's output. To remove this they added `| sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed -e 's/\r*$//'` after the SSH output so the new command would look like this:

`ssh -t -t -i id_dsa headless@remoteserver.com "ps -auxwww |grep pipeline| wc -l" | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | sed -e 's/\r*$//'`

### Troubleshooting Tip

If you come across this post and are experiencing a similar issue the cause is most likely characters not visible when you look at the command's output, for example through an echo call. Even logging your output in a file/editor might not indicate there's a hidden character.

An easy/quick way to determine if this is the case is to add `|cat -A` to the end of your SSH command and run it in your terminal. Running your command with `|cat -A`(*case sensitive*) at the end of it in your terminal will return the output with hidden characters visible. *Note a `$` in the output indicates a new line.*

For example when I used this on my command it returned `1^M$` but an echo call in my bash file was only outputting a `1` along with the error `integer expression expected`. In my case I added the accepted answer along with `|tr -d '\n'` at the end of it to remove the extra line. In my bash file my final command was:

```
while [ "$(ssh -t username@remoteserver "my command here" |sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' |sed -e 's/\r*$//' |tr -d '\n')" -gt 1 ] ; do
  # do something cool
done
```